# Lazarus component for Multimedia manipulation and WinCE compatible

Tags: components, windows-ce, multimedia, lazarus

I would just like to know if there are Multimedia components for Lazarus and is compatible with WinCE platform. I tried the ACS(Audio Component Suite)but it gives an error when I compiled it. Plus, it doesn't support video manipulation.I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've no clue if the normal multimedia api's are actually supported on wince. Porting existing components might be hard. I'd start to research wince api wrt multimedia, then select a delphi component that is closest and then port it.